# Dynamodb Nodejs SDK Scan returning Attribute names

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm using the AWS SDK with Express and Nodejs. I am doing a scan on the table Users. I want to map the attributes so they are dont appear in the JSON. 
I have the following code:

```
app.get('/users',function(req, res) {

var params = {
    TableName: 'Users'
};

dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred

    } else {
        console.log(data);
                   // successful response
        res.send(data);
    }
});
```

});

It returns:

```
 {"Items":[{"id":{"S":"test"}}]}
```

I want it to return:

```
{"Items":[{"id":"test"}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

The DynamoDB Document SDK for NodeJS does exactly what you want:
https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-document-js-sdk

There are instructions on how to get started and code snippets for basic API calls in the README.